# symfony2 form error vs field error theme (twig)

Tags: symfony, twig

In Twig, is there a way to define a **different theme** for field errors as oppose to form related errors like CSRF error or composite unique constraints?

I want to display the field errors with a `<span>` and the form errors with a `<ul>`

```
{{ form_errors(form) }}        

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form_label(form.tabla) }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(form.tabla) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.tabla) }}
            </td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ form_label(form.descripcion) }}</td>
            <td>
                {{ form_widget(form.descripcion) }}
                {{ form_errors(form.descripcion) }}
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is my form theme that is being used for both cases (not what I want).

```
{% block field_errors %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <span class="val-error">
            {% for error in errors %}
                {{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')~'. ' }}
            {% endfor %}
        </span>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock field_errors %}
```

Is there a way to differentiate both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `field_*` is removed in 2.3 the approved solution will no longer work. A hacky solution I have found is

```
{% block form_errors %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        {% if form.parent is empty %}
            <ul class="val-error">
                {% for error in errors %}
                    <li>{{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')~'. ' }}</li>
                {% endfor %}
            </ul>
        {% else %}
             <span class="val-error">
                 {% for error in errors %}
                     {{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters,  'validators')~'. ' }}
                 {% endfor %}
             </span>
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

So basically what this does is if there is no parent, it knows it is the top level.

Answer (score 4):

Form class extends Field. If you set a new theme to field it will be applied to form.
You should override the field_errors block as you did, and then define the form_errors block using another template (with th ul tag).

```
{% block field_errors %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <span class="val-error">
            {% for error in errors %}
                {{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')~'. ' }}
            {% endfor %}
        </span>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock field_errors %}

{% block form_errors %}
    {% if errors|length > 0 %}
        <ul class="val-error">
            {% for error in errors %}
                <li>{{ error.messageTemplate|trans(error.messageParameters, 'validators')~'. ' }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock form_errors %}
```

Comment: Thanks man, that was a big help because that block "form_errors" is not shown in "fom_div_layout.html.twig" and I didn't even know it existed

Comment: I have a question about that. In the https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig said that field_* will be deprecated in Symfony 2.1, to be removed in 2.3. How to do that without use this?

Comment: @Ztere0 did you find out if it's save to use the field_error block? for me it seems not if it'll be deprecated in 2.3

Comment: Finally I have not investigated anything more about that. Sorry

Comment: @Ztere0 I know it is old, but I have posted a hacky answer that works in 2.3